# angular js repeat in the defined numbers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in `Angular JS`. I am working on a `caraousel` in angular js. I want to repeat a `DIV` which is having a SET of 4.

I can see now divs are created after using `ng-if="$index % 4 == 0"` but I am not able to get the 4 items.

How can I use INDEX for getting 4 items in my repetitive `DIV`?

Please have a look at the code as following :

```
<div class="carousel-inner" ng-init="getSpecialDeals()">
  <div class="item" ng-class="{active: $index==0}" ng-repeat="specialDeals in SpecialDealsList" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <!-- ITEM-->
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail product-item">
          <a href="#">
            <img ng-src="{{specialDeals.images}}">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3>   {{specialDeals.name}} </h3> 
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="http://www.bootstraptor.com">View details »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- ITEM-->

      <!-- ITEM-->
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail product-item">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/16/03/33/160333e0e9d6563729313131ff755964.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3> {{specialDeals.name}}</h3> 
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="http://www.bootstraptor.com">View details »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- ITEM-->
      <!-- ITEM-->
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail product-item">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/16/03/33/160333e0e9d6563729313131ff755964.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3>Product name</h3>
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="http://www.bootstraptor.com">View details »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- ITEM-->
      <!-- ITEM-->
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail product-item">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/16/03/33/160333e0e9d6563729313131ff755964.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>
        <h3>Product name</h3> 
        <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="http://www.bootstraptor.com">View details »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- ITEM-->

    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

```
function _getSpecialDeals() {
    if (document.getElementById('FCDivID')) {
        $scope.requestData = $scope.requestData + '&category_id=' + $scope.featuredCategoryId;
    }

    $http(
        {
            method : 'POST',
            url : $scope.base + '/specialoffers/GetSpecialDeals',
        crossDomain : true,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'key' : 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        data : $scope.requestData,
    })
    .then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                document.getElementById("gifLoader").style.display = "none";
                //document.getElementById("gifLoader1").style.display = "none";

                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";

                if(response.data.SpecialProductsList!=undefined){
                    if(response.data.SpecialProductsList.length<5){
                    $scope.flagArrow=false;}
                }
                if (response.data.status == "200") {
                    $scope.specialDeals = response.data;
                    $scope.totalPages = response.data.total_pages;

                    if ($scope.pageNumber > 1) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.SpecialProductsList.length; i++) {
                            $scope.SpecialDealsList
                                    .push(response.data.SpecialProductsList[i]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $scope.SpecialDealsList = $scope.specialDeals.SpecialProductsList;
                    }
                    if (document
                            .getElementById("list_item")) {
                        $scope.SpecialDealsList
                                .push({
                                    "product_id" : "1",
                                    "name" : "Get All Deals",
                                    "product_selling_price" : "0.00",
                                    "wish_list" : "False",
                                    "images" : "img/view-more.jpg",
                                    "product_special_from_date" : "",
                                    "product_special_to_date" : "",
                                    "product_special_price" : "",
                                })
                    };
                }
                /*document.getElementById("wpf-loader-two").style.display = "none";*/
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Read your post once and check if it meaningful? where is the controller? **getSpecialDeals()** means? **SpecialDeals** means?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:Found it.. You have to use ng-repeat to iterate through specialDeals. Hope this helps

```
 <h3 ng-repeat="x in specialDeals">{{x.name}}</h3>
```

Although I was not able to make the code run, I would just like to point out a few mistakes in order to be helpful,
it should be:-

```
if(response.data.SpecialProductsList!==undefined){
```

instead of a single '='

and instead of writing function getSpecialDeals() ,do this :

```
$scope.getSpecialDeals=function () {  if (document.getElementById('FCDivID')).....
```